# How to verify Firewall Session Table or Stateful database entries on Cisco ZBF configured Boxes?

Tags: cisco, firewall, security

How to verify Firewall Session Table or Stateful database entries on Cisco Zone Based Firewall configured Boxes? what's the command to show the content/records of that table? is there any command like the NAT table show commands or what?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
show policy-map type inspect %zone-pair% %zone-pair-name% sessions
```

This is a great doc on the Cisco Support forums for troubleshooting ZBF's

https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/60736/zbfw-troubleshooting-command-list